# Multi word match using Regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Okay I've checked out the pages suggested after typing the Title and still can't find the answer.

I'm using Notepad++ which seems to have it's own version of regular expression syntax but I'm not skilled with regular expressions in the first place. However I really would like to use one for the type of searches I'm doing in a extremely long log file.

What I need to do is find lines where two or more words are found not an or '|' but an and.  All the words in the query must be present in each line. So if there are two that I'm matching "(cat) (dog)" it would return all rows where cat and dog both appear in the line but not lines where only cat or only dog appear.

Likewise on three element searches "(cat) (dog) (hamster)" if it found cat and dog together but no hamster it would not return that line but if it found all three present it would.

I was told that just putting a space between these would function as an 'and' but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm on Notepad++ v7.3.3

Comment: How about placing a greedy dot preceding / following each word `.*cat.*dog.*hamster.*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regexps, the space  is considered literally, so "cat dog hamster" is the concatenation of `cat`, , `dog`,  and `hamster`.

In the above comment it has been suggested the following regex:

```
.*cat.*dog.*hamster.*
```

where `.*` means "0 or more other characters". But with this pattern the order of words matters.

If you don't want the order to matter, you can use the following expression:

```
^(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3)
```

that means the begin of the line (`^`) has to be followed (`(?=)`) by `word1`, and by `word2` and by `word3`, after any number of other characters.

Comment: Works like a champ... exactly what I was looking for in your third example!

Comment: Notepad++ has the proper checkbox for case-insensitive search. Alternatively, you can add `(?i)` at the begin of the regex, or you can replace every `a` with `[Aa]`.